# Unable to retrieve a refresh token or get reloadAuthResponse to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, google-signin

I've got a rails api that is authorising a login attempt on the client side (react) using the react-google-login package.

Everything is working correctly with the current set up that returns me an access token and a user object... however this has been problematic in that the access tokens only last 60 minutes at which point my users are booted out of the app.

Ultimately I want to be able to get a new token before the 60 minutes is up if my user has been active.... I have tried to get a new token using the reloadAuthResponse() method but this only returns a strange object and not a promise as I have seen in other examples.

I have then tried to retrieve an access token in the backend by passing an offline token, but my attempts are receiving an "invalid grant" message from the response.

endpoint for this;

`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token`

Can someone point me in the direction of either some documentation that could shine a light on what I'm doing or help me debug the setup a bit.

Any help is greatly appreciated.